# showing images on mouseover of another images using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function bigpic()
{
document.getElementById('img2').src="<?php echo '../images/$img2';?>";  
}
```

```
 <img name="img1" src="<?php echo "../images/$img1";?>" width="100px" height="100px"    onmouseover="bigpic()"/>
 <img name="img2" src="" width="32" height="32" alt="" id="img2"/>
```

`$img1` and `$img2` are fetched from mysql database and fetching is working well. But `$img2` is not displayed while `mouseover` on img1. This is what i have tried. What is wrong here.

Comment: Try with `onmouseover="javascript:bigpic()"`, does that help?

Comment: Try changing to this:     document.getElementById('img1').src

Comment: it doesnot work. it displays blank image..

Comment: echo '../images/$img2'... could you post generated html?

Comment: i didnot get what you are asking for.. @nevermind

Comment: It's the src of $img2 a valid one? I mean, does it exist on server?

Comment: To print this line `document.getElementById('img2').src="<?php echo '../images/$img2';?>";` from your browsers view source, rather than from the php file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
document.getElementById('img2').src="<?php echo '../images/$img2';?>";
```

To this

```
document.getElementById('img2').src="<?php echo "../images/$img2";?>";
```

Reason, single quoted strings does not evaluate a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked fine with me using static images. Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function bigpic()
{
document.getElementById('img2').src="<?php echo '../images/'.$img2 ;?>";  
}
</script>

<img name="img1" src="<?php echo "../images/" . $img1;?>" width="100px" height="100px"    onmouseover="bigpic()"/>
 <img name="img2" src="" width="32" height="32" alt="" id="img2"/>
```